# respond to "I hope I'm successful!"

Tags: conversation, responses

One of my friends who has applied to a university told me "I hope I'm successful!". How can I respond to that? Is it correct to say "I'm sure you will be fine"? Any better suggestions?

Comment: "I hope I'm successful!" is awkward... did he mean "I think I'm successful (because I was enrolled to a top-tier university)" or "I hope I will be successful (because many people who went there came out successful)"?

Comment: I think the first, but she he didn't use "I think"

Comment: If they do not yet know the outcome of their application then "I hope I'm successful" would mean "I hope I will be successful" in which case your suggestion would work. Can you edit to clarify the exact circumstances of the application?

Comment: **Good luck!** is generally a useful response to statements such as these.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Using present tense for future hopes isn't "awkward". Per [this NGram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hope+I+am+successful%2Chope+I+will+be+successful&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10), we use *I hope I **am*** as often as *I hope I **will be***. More importantly, for the *contracted* form, [***I hope I'm successful***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hope+I%27m+successful%2Chope+I%27ll+be+successful&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chope%20I%20%27m%20successful%3B%2Cc0) is far more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I'm sure you will be fine" (or "I'm sure you'll be fine") is perfectly acceptable, yes.  The phrase might be clearer as "I hope I'm successful in applying to this university", i.e. they're hoping that their application is successful, they're hoping that they succeed in applying.  They're not generically hoping to be successful in life, so any response which suggests you think they'll be accepted to the university would be fine.